# meteor call async in meteor

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

This is another asynchronous topic for meteor, and i'm sorry for that ! I read so much things about wrapasync, promise, future, fibers etc... that i'm a bit lost !

My problem is simple, in my code I just want a return of the server who is returning the current hostname from :

```
"getHost" : function(){
      return this.connection.httpHeaders.host;
 }
```

I'm calling this at the beggining of my program in the onCreated helper :

```
Template.printjoblistList.onCreated(function () {
    Meteor.call("getHost", function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log("error " + err + " : " + data);
        }else {
            Session.set("printJobList_Host", data)
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is : I have my Session.set who are executed after my Session.get. This Session.get is executed by this :

In my template :

```
<a href="{{getPdf}}">{{getPdf}}</a>
```

In my helper :

```
Template.registerHelper("getPdf", function() {
    var myReturn = Session.get('printJobList_Host'); + "/pdf/" + pdfFileName;
    return myReturn;
});
```

So, I would like to understand how to use wrapAsync to get this clearly !
Thanks for your help !

Comment: On the client, you can't. `wrapAsync` is to make asynchronous code look synchronous thanks to Fibers and only work in a Node environment (the server). On the client, you're stuck with classical asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

The `Session.get` may happen before the `Session.set`, but that should be fine, because when the `Session.set` is called, the `Session.get` will be called again too (at least it is the case in a regular helper.)

If that doesn't work for you, try using the `Session.get` inside a `Tracker.autorun()`